# Mac OS - get app window to front

Tags: python, macos, electron, pid

I have electron based app. I open url in electron window using

```
launcher_process = subprocess.Popen(launcher_path + [launcher_url, 'main', runfromsrc])
self.main_window_pid = launcher_process.pid

In js file create window

mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: w, height: h, icon: __dirname + '\\abc.ico', resizable:false, title:"ABC"})
```

This works fine and opens my app url. Now if I change screen to other app like safari. Then from agent app in tray I want to bring electron window in front. Agent app in tray is created from native NSApplication.

I tried

```
from AppKit import NSRunningApplication, NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps
            ap = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier_(electron_pid)
            ap.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
```

This do not work. ap is None.

Is there a way to get hold of electron window through pid and get it in front.

Comment: May I know what the underscore at the end of methods name do ?

Comment: In PyObj to to objective C method _ is used.

Comment: How to you retrieve `electron_pid` ? According to documentation the return value your be `nil if the application has no process identifier`

Comment: As of now this is not possible because that is how Mac desktop works. When an app is on full screen mode, e.g. Safari, another app cannot be opened on top of it.